# How to make sure that a 4 number input is 4 getting numbers?

Tags: c#, input, numbers, digits

My input is a year in 4 digits between 1900-3000. So the input has to be 4 digits 1994, 2022,2950.

However, how do I check if the input is only 3 digits or less or 5 digigts or more?
I have alread made an if statement if it's over 1900 or 3000.

```
   if (YearNumb<1900 || YearNumb>3000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Du angav inte ett år mellan 1900 och 3000.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            return;
```

Comment: `if(yearNumb < 1000 || yearNumb > 9999)`

Comment: what type is `YearNumb`?

Comment: It is an int converted from a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (YearNumb<1900 || YearNumb>3000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Du angav inte ett år mellan 1900 och 3000.");
            Console.ReadLine();
            return;
        }
else if (YearNumb.ToString().Length != 4)
           {
            Console.WriteLine("text");
            Console.ReadLine();
            return;
        }
```

Convert to string and check length.

Comment: Doesn't work properly, if I enter 1700 it does not execute it.

Comment: Oops, edited above to solve that issue and the ability to show a different message.

Comment: @Baxtex, there is no way that the second `if` will ever be entered. Its a pointless `ToString()` call followed by a redundant length check. If `YearNumb` is an `int` it cannot be between `1900` and `3000` and have a length other than `4`. Unless, I suppose, the culture you are under has a non decimal representation for numbers.

Answer (score -1):

ok,

```
if (YearNumb < 0)
{
    ...
} 
else if (YearNumb < 1000)
{
    ...
}
else if (YearNumb > 9999)
{
    ...
}
else if (YearNumb < 1900 || YearNumb > 3000)
{
    ...
}
```

Is probably more like what you are looking for.

Comment: A number with 3 or 5 characters will pass int.tryparse

Comment: @user1948635 but, the parsed value won't be geater than `1899` and less than `3001`. So `valid` will remain `false` unless `input` is valid.